# Android client server won't show object

Tags: android, android-asynctask, firebase, client-server

I made simple Client server to android.
I have problem when I send an object from server to the client.
The object is received ok and when I check the log, it shows me the the object was sent successfully.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to get this object and put it in my `ListView` adapter.
The adapter works, I checked it with a random `ArrayList` I created.
My issue is when I'm trying to to put the values of `AsyncTask` in my adapter.

```
public class RestaurantListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<Resturant> res = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListAdapter adapter;
    private Firebase restRef = new Firebase("https://restmeup.firebaseio.com/restaurants");
    private Client mClient;
  //  private connectTask  t = (connectTask)new connectTask().execute();


    public RestaurantListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new connectTask().execute();    

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //     new connectTask(getView()).execute();
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);    

        ListView restaurantList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(), res, getActivity());
        restaurantList.setAdapter(adapter);

       // connectTask  t = (connectTask)new connectTask().execute();
        if (mClient != null) {
            mClient.sendMessage("bar");
        }
        SqlQueriesConverter sql = new SqlQueriesConverter();
        sql.getResurantsListQuery("bar");
        //       sql.getUserFavoritesResturants(accessToken.getUserId());
        mClient.sendMessage(sql.getQuery());
        //   t.setArray(res);


        mClient.sendMessage("/quit");
        mClient.stopClient();

        final EditText searchText = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchListView);

        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                System.out.println("Before---------");
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String text = searchText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println("array: " + res.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                System.out.println("After---------");
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }


    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<?>,ArrayList<?>,Client> {
     //   private Client mClient;
        private ArrayList<?> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected Client doInBackground(ArrayList<?>... message) {

            //we create a Client object and
            mClient = new Client(new Client.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(ArrayList<?> message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    // publishProgress(message);
                    onProgressUpdate(message);
                }
            });

            mClient.run();
            return null;
        }

        // @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(ArrayList<?>... values) {
              super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            ArrayList<?> arr2;
            if (values[0].get(0) instanceof Resturant){
                Log.d("step 1", "1");
                if (((ArrayList<?>)values[0]).get(0)instanceof Resturant) {

                    // arr2 = (ArrayList<Resturant>) values[0];
                    res = (ArrayList<Resturant>) values[0];
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.d("array",res.toString());    

                }
            }
            if (values[0].get(0)instanceof Review){
                arr2 = (ArrayList<Review>) values[0];
            }
            if (values[0].get(0)instanceof UserFavorites){
                arr2 = (ArrayList<Review>) values[0];
                Log.d("step 2", "2");
            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to change to use the `AsyncTask` as you intend. The first change you need is to return the `ArrayList` you get from your `mClient` in the `doInBackground` method. This is a bit troublesome because it looks like the `Client` is already running asynchronously since you pass a callback to get the result (this is the `Client.OnMessageReceived` anonymous class you have there). The second change would be to implement `onPostExecute` on your `AsyncTask` since that is where the results from `doInBackground` are sent. You'd add the result sent from `doInBackground` to your adapter in there.

In any case, since it looks like `Client` is already performing the work asynchronously, you shouldn't need to use an `AsyncTask` at all. Just implement the logic to add the results to your adapter in the `Client.OnMessageReceived` callback.

Just get the code you already have in `onProgressUpdate` and throw it inside `messageReceived`. Something like this:

```
mClient = new Client(new Client.OnMessageReceived() {
    @Override
    //here the messageReceived method is implemented
    public void messageReceived(ArrayList<?> values) {
        if (values[0].get(0) instanceof Resturant){
            Log.d("step 1", "1");
            if (((ArrayList<?>)values[0]).get(0)instanceof Resturant) {
                res = (ArrayList<Resturant>) values[0];
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("array",res.toString());    
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It still not working. maybe I have problem with the client class ?

Comment: I don't know what your `Client` class looks likes, but given the way it was structured, it seems to be running the code asynchronously. I'd recommend you have a look at the Firebase documentation on how to retrieve data as that would be the most direct way: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html